# Can I upload data to only part of a json file?

Tags: python, json, file, dictionary

I am wondering if there is any way to update the json file without having to completely rewrite the json file. As shown in the example below I first had to retrieve all the data from the json file then add to/ edit the original data then rewrite the new data dictionary over the original file. Is it possible to just edit a few lines of the json file directly?

I have a main file and a json file that look as follows:

**MAIN FILE**

```
import json

with open('animals.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

attributes = {"Food": "", "Size": "", "Habitat": ""}

data["Animal 1"]["Food"] = "Meat"
data["Animal 1"]["Size"] = "Medium"
data["Animal 1"]["Habitat"] = "Savannah"

attributes["Food"] = "Nuts"
attributes["Size"] = "Small"
attributes["Habitat"] = "Forest"
data["Animal 3"] =  dict(attributes)

# attributes["Food"] = "Plankton"
# attributes["Size"] = "Large"
# attributes["Habitat"] = "Ocean"
# data["Animal 2"] =  dict(attributes)

with open('animals.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

**JSON FILE**

```
{
    "Animal 1": {
        "Food": "Banana",
        "Size": "Medium",
        "Habitat": "Jungle"
    },
    "Animal 2": {
        "Food": "Plankton",
        "Size": "Large",
        "Habitat": "Ocean"
    }
}
```

Currently the code updates the json file (Animal 1 attributes and adds  Animal 3) to look like this:

```
{
    "Animal 1": {
        "Food": "Meat",
        "Size": "Medium",
        "Habitat": "Savannah"
    },
    "Animal 2": {
        "Food": "Plankton",
        "Size": "Large",
        "Habitat": "Ocean"
    },
    "Animal 3": {
        "Food": "Nuts",
        "Size": "Small",
        "Habitat": "Forest"
    }
}
```

Are there any alternatives to this method?

Comment: If you're looking to make this scalable I'd probably use something like sqlite, which would give you the ability to pick out specific records and edit them.

Comment: It's nothing to do with JSON; *files* do not work that way. Also, none of this has anything to do with "uploading", which means *transferring* your file from your computer to a server.

Comment: So I can't use it with json files @dir

Comment: @ChristopherOjo I have no idea what your long term goals are, but to answer this question: no. You have to rewrite the file every time.

Comment: the whole problem is "uploading" to a "json" "file" how is it not relevant? I understand the uploading part but json and file are necessary for the question.

Comment: @ChristopherOjo You're looking for words like "appending" and "editing specific lines without full rewrite". Uploading always refers to a transfer of a file.

Comment: As an aside, if you want to create new dictionaries following some pattern, it will be easier to start fresh each time, rather than modifying a template and making a copy each time. For something this simple you can just write out the whole new dict: `data["Animal 3"] = {"Food": "Nuts", "Size": "Small", "Habitat": "Forest"}`.

Comment: "the whole problem is "uploading" to a "json" "file"" No, it is not. The word "uploading" *does not mean what you appear to think it means*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yeah my bad, the reason I made a copy of the dictionary each time is because the project that I am actually using the code for it is declared in a loop, making it easier to update it with a template.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you'll scale up the process with much more data, so this **json data overwritting** can be easily achieve by using **pandas dataframes**. The main thing here is that **you don't have to worry about each json field being updated** as you showed with your code. I won't go through saving/writing file thing, as it's not the problem.  If not for the json info, the solution **takes up to only 6 lines of code** with this approach. The step-by-step explanation I show after the full code.

By the way, you can also read from json file directly by using `pd.read_json('file_name.json')` and writing to it with `datraframe_object.to_json('file_name.json')`.

**Full code for those who want to reproduce:**

```
import json
import pandas as pd

original_json = {
    "Animal 1": {
        "Food": "Banana",
        "Size": "Medium",
        "Habitat": "Jungle"
    },
    "Animal 2": {
        "Food": "Plankton",
        "Size": "Large",
        "Habitat": "Ocean"
    }
}

overwrite_json = {
    "Animal 1": {
        "Food": "Meat",
        "Size": "Medium",
        "Habitat": "Savannah"
    },
    "Animal 2": {
        "Food": "Plankton",
        "Size": "Large",
        "Habitat": "Ocean"
    },
    "Animal 3": {
        "Food": "Nuts",
        "Size": "Small",
        "Habitat": "Forest"
    }
}

#here the six lines to get your updated json info
original_frame = pd.DataFrame(original_json).T
overwrite_frame = pd.DataFrame(overwrite_json).T
original_frame['index'] = original_frame.index
overwrite_frame['index'] = overwrite_frame.index

updated_frame = original_frame.merge(overwrite_frame,how='right').set_index('index')
final_json = updated_frame.to_json(orient='index',indent=4)
print(final_json)
```

The output:

```
{
    "Animal 1":{
        "Food":"Meat",
        "Size":"Medium",
        "Habitat":"Savannah"
    },
    "Animal 2":{
        "Food":"Plankton",
        "Size":"Large",
        "Habitat":"Ocean"
    },
    "Animal 3":{
        "Food":"Nuts",
        "Size":"Small",
        "Habitat":"Forest"
    }
}
```

**Step-by-step explanation**:

1. Import pandas, which is commonly used for data science, so it's well documented and used by many.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
```

2. Here I assume you'll do your 'with open' file thing. For simplicity I'll just assign the json objects with the info you provided.

```
original_json = {
    "Animal 1": {
        "Food": "Banana",
        "Size": "Medium",
        "Habitat": "Jungle"
    },
    "Animal 2": {
        "Food": "Plankton",
        "Size": "Large",
        "Habitat": "Ocean"
    }
}

overwrite_json = {
    "Animal 1": {
        "Food": "Meat",
        "Size": "Medium",
        "Habitat": "Savannah"
    },
    "Animal 2": {
        "Food": "Plankton",
        "Size": "Large",
        "Habitat": "Ocean"
    },
    "Animal 3": {
        "Food": "Nuts",
        "Size": "Small",
        "Habitat": "Forest"
    }
}
```

3. Create pandas dataframes of the json information. I transposed (`.T`) here to keep your original json records orientation.

```
original_frame = pd.DataFrame(original_json).T
overwrite_frame = pd.DataFrame(overwrite_json).T
```

The dataframes look like this. They're indexed by 'Animal 1', 'Animal 2' and so on:

```
print(original_frame)
            Food    Size   Habitat     
Animal 1    Banana  Medium  Jungle  
Animal 2  Plankton   Large   Ocean

print(overwrite_frame)
             Food    Size   Habitat     
Animal 1      Meat  Medium  Savannah  
Animal 2  Plankton   Large     Ocean  
Animal 3      Nuts   Small    Forest
```

4. Store the indexes of each dataframe in a new column for later use.

```
original_frame['index'] = original_frame.index
overwrite_frame['index'] = overwrite_frame.index
#example of 'index' column created
print(original_frame)
           Food    Size    Habitat     index
Animal 1    Banana  Medium  Jungle  Animal 1
Animal 2  Plankton   Large   Ocean  Animal 2
```

5. Then we merge the two dataframes, overwritting the original_frame with the overwrite_frame. See that I use `how='right'` to give preference for the `overwrite_frame` and `set_index` to use the previously saved index columns.

```
updated_frame = original_frame.merge(overwrite_frame,how='right').set_index('index')
print(update_frame)
             Food    Size   Habitat
index                               
Animal 1      Meat  Medium  Savannah
Animal 2  Plankton   Large     Ocean
Animal 3      Nuts   Small    Forest
```

6. Then simply generate a new json from the resulting dataframe

```
final_json = updated_frame.to_json(orient='index',indent=4)
print(final_json)
{
    "Animal 1":{
        "Food":"Meat",
        "Size":"Medium",
        "Habitat":"Savannah"
    },
    "Animal 2":{
        "Food":"Plankton",
        "Size":"Large",
        "Habitat":"Ocean"
    },
    "Animal 3":{
        "Food":"Nuts",
        "Size":"Small",
        "Habitat":"Forest"
    }
}
```

**If I got your question right, this solves your bottleneck!**